# Confused on whether to express time complexity with theta notation or Big Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

How to decide on expressing time complexity of algorithm ?

Should we choose to express time complexity in terms of `O(n)` or `theta(n)` ? Because a function `f(n)` can be expressed as either `Big-Oh(g(n))` or `theta (g(n))`.

When do we choose big-oh over theta ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Big Theta notation when you want to also specify a lower bound. `f(n) = O(g(n))` says that `f` is bounded above by `g`, whereas `f(n) = Theta(g(n))` says that `f` is bounded both above and below by `g`.

In other words, there are constants `k1` and `k2` such that `k1 * |g(n)| <= |f(n)| <= k2 * |g(n)|`